# Form inside <p:Dialog> doesnt set values to Entities

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a Java Web Application (WAR) in Weblogic 10.3.0:

- JSF 2.0
- Primefaces 3.5
- jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar (If i use el-api-2.2.jar and el-impl-2.2.jar is the same)
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
- Eclipselink (JPA 2.1)
- hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
- JSTL 1.1
- Java EE 5

I have a `<h:form/>` inside a `<p:dialog/>` to edit/create entities and persist them to the Database.

My problem is the `<p:commandButton/>` doesn't invoke the `actionListener` when the values are set directly to the entity's properties. For example, here is my code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="Name:" for="name" />
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{Servidores.selectedEntity.name}" title="Name" />
    <p:outputLabel value="IP:" for="ip" />
    <p:inputText id="ip" value="#{Servidores.selectedEntity.ip}" title="IP" />

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" oncomplete="appEditingDialog.hide();" actionListener="#{Servers.processEntityAndRefresh()}"/>
</h:form>
```

But if i set values to a simple String variable declared in the bean and not in the entity it works. Like this:

```
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{Servidores.stringInMyBean}" title="Name" />
```

I thought it was a validation problem but if i put this form outside the Dialog it works.

What could be the problem and the solution here ? I've seen people putting the properties directly in the `@ManagedBean` but, wow, I can't mix the Model and the Controller.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you didn't got a NPE in the server log? Did you actually look in the server log?

Comment: I don't see a messages component, probably something goes wrong and you don't see it? You could add `<h:messages />` or `<p:messages />` to check that.

Comment: @BalusC I posted the solution to this and all the problems i had ! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solve this and other problems i had:

In my Template.xhtml i made sure the declarations are like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

because instead of "java.sun.com" i had something with "xmlns.com" (something like that, i dont know why). My problems with the EL were solved but a new problem came out: Everything was big: font, components, etc.

I had to fix everything with CSS but i didn't like that way, it was unnaceptable! Plus, Dialogs were showing in the bottom of the page. So after trying some things, i fixed it making the Template Clients using `HTML` instead of just `<ui:composition/>`. So i could delete all the "forced changes" i made to my CSS files (I really don't know why that behavior with just `<ui:composition/>` ) .

But wait! , in a part of a page the problems came back! Calling methods/properties in the `ManagedBean` from a Datatable wasn't working properly again and it was because of the Primefaces `<p:Dashboard/>` tag called "Disabled" which i set it to true to not let the user move the panels. My datatable was inside of a Panel which was inside of a Dashboard, after setting it to false everything was working properly (I guess it is a primefaces bug).

Then, i just move from Primefaces 3.5 to 4.0 and used JSTL 1.2 instead of 1.1

But yeah, the main problem was because of the wrong links when declaring xmlns, xmlns:h, xmlns:f, etc.